# regex unable to allow apostrophe

Tags: php, regex

I am experiencing a strange problem with a regular expression I have already used before.
The goal is to allow the user to enter his name, with letters, hyphen, and apostrophes if needed in a php form.
My regex is:

```
 "/^[\w\s'àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ-]+$/i"
```

But... everything is allowed but the apostrophe. Escaping it will not change. Why?

Comment: As presented it does accept apostrophes. Show your actual test string.

Comment: Are you sure you entered the correct apostrophe here?

Comment: well, my test string will be either ' or d'Yves or anything. And yes this is the only apostrophe I can enter on my keyboard, in fact the one I would be entering on a website...

Comment: but in fact, I test it on my mac. Would it be different on the real website server (from Arvixe, that is)

Comment: Well online it works. I do not understand why my mac won't allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal with unicode characters, you can do:

```
/^[\pN\pL\pP\pZ]+$/
```

where:

```
\pN  stands for any number
\pL  stands for any letter
\pP  stands for any punctuation
\pZ  stands for any space
```

It matches names like:

```
d'Alembert  
d’Alembert    (note the different apos from above)
Jean-François
O'Connors
```

Comment: Much better too, as it actually allows names from outside of france.